# Implement Stop click of MediaStore Intent on video capture

Tags: java, android

How can I trigger a method when I click on Stop button while recording video in MediaStore.

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

I am starting the capture video with this code. I just don't know is it posible to implement the Stop button and in the implementation to close the MediaStore and start an Activity.

Here is the Stop Button :-P Cheers mates
[image: Some big Stop button]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to start an activity in the implementation of the Stop button from MediaStore.

What you can do though is that when you press the Stop button the startActivityForResult method will return with an int code number (this is in your activity).

You should check for that number and **then** start another activity.